# Built in webcam doesn't work - Acer Aspire A515-57G

Tags: webcam, acer, uvc

The webcam was working when the seller tested it with me while it still had windows, but it's not working now with ubuntu 22.04.

lsusb detected the device:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0408:4033 Quanta Computer, Inc. ACER HD User Facing
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 062a:4106 MosArt Semiconductor Corp. Wireless Mouse 2.4G
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 062a:4101 MosArt Semiconductor Corp. Wireless Keyboard/Mouse
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. AX201 Bluetooth
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

dmesg output:

```
[    3.464886] uvcvideo 3-7:1.1: Failed to query (129) UVC probe control : 26 (exp. 48).
[    3.464919] uvcvideo 3-7:1.1: Failed to initialize the device (-5).
[    3.501727] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
```

I looked up for a module, and it seems to be there:

```
/usr/include/linux/uvcvideo.h
/usr/include/linux/usb/g_uvc.h
/usr/lib/modules/5.15.0-25-generic/kernel/drivers/media/usb/uvc
/usr/lib/modules/5.15.0-25-generic/kernel/drivers/media/usb/uvc/uvcvideo.ko
/usr/lib/modules/5.15.0-25-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/gadget/function/usb_f_uvc.ko
/usr/lib/modules/5.15.0-41-generic/kernel/drivers/media/usb/uvc
/usr/lib/modules/5.15.0-41-generic/kernel/drivers/media/usb/uvc/uvcvideo.ko
/usr/lib/modules/5.15.0-41-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/gadget/function/usb_f_uvc.ko
```

I have been using ubuntu for a few years now, but I am not that experienced when it comes to using the terminal. Hopefully, someone can help me with this.

Thanks.

Comment: Google didn't find any other result for this product than this one that seems to be yours: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2477627&p=14106479

Comment: I have exactly the same problem and unfortunately no solution. Are there new findings?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there is a solution for the camera https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2000947

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).